# Linux - Editar vários arquivos usando outro arquivo como fonte

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

Tenho um arquivo (listanome.txt) com vários nomes, um por linha.

Preciso editar ou remove todos os nomes que estão em `listanome.txt` de vários outros arquivos

Com [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) eu acho quais arquivos devem ser ditados, porém são muitos.

```
grep -Ff listanome.txt /caminho
```

Não estou conseguindo usar o [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) ou [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) usando como base um arquivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o seu arquivo de índice `listanome.txt` para fazer um script a ser utilizado pelo `sed` para remover as linhas:

Para um `listanome.txt` conforme abaixo...

```
$ cat listanome.txt 
ze
jao
juca
```

...o seguinte `sed` transforma em um script de exclusão para cada nome da lista:

```
$ sed 's/^/\//; s/$/\/d/' listanome.txt
/ze/d
/jao/d
/juca/d
```

Assim, passe tal comando `sed` para a flag `-f` de um novo `sed`, que executará tal script em todos os arquivos a serem afetados, supostamente contidos no diretório `caminho`:

```
$ sed --in-place=.bak -f <(sed 's/^/\//; s/$/\/d/' listanome.txt) /caminho/*
```

Isso deletará todas as linhas de todos os arquivos do diretório `caminho` ***que contêm*** os nomes de `listanome.txt`, efetuando cópias de segurança com a extensão ".bak" para cada arquivo alterado.

Caso seu requisito mude, altere o primeiro `sed` de acordo com o que deseja, por exemplo:

- Para deletar todas as linhas idênticas às do índice:

  ```
  $ sed 's/^/\/^/; s/$/$\/d/' listanome.txt
  /^ze$/d
  /^jao$/d
  /^juca$/d
  ```
- Para substituir o conteúdo da linha pela string "REMOVER":

  ```
  $ sed 's/^/\/^\.\*/; s/$/\.\*$\/REMOVER\/g/' listanome.txt
  /^.*ze.*$/REMOVER/g
  /^.*jao.*$/REMOVER/g
  /^.*juca.*$/REMOVER/g
  ```

Comment: Eu acho que esse aqui pode funcionar!! Genial, deixa eu brincar e retorno aqui :)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, you rock! Vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `xargs` para realizar a tarefa desejada, segue abaixo um exemplo onde eu listo um diretório e pego todos os arquivos .cfg e insiro uma linha nos arquivos encontrados.:

```
ls *.cfg | xargs sed -i"23i#####################################################"
```

entendendo melhor o comando acima:

`ls *.cfg` -> lista todos os arquivos que terminam com a extensão `.cfg`

`| xargs` -> pega os dados que foram exibidos no comando anterior para aplicar o comando seguinte.

`sed -i"23i#####################################################"` -> insere uma linha em cada arquivo encontrado no comando `ls`, nesse caso estou inserindo na linha 23 de cada arquivo.

Creio que na sua necessidade o ideal seria criar um for que leia cada linha do seu primeiro arquivo e apos isso aplicar a ação necessária.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Infelizmente não consegui fazer funcionar assim porque preciso editar a linha que contém o nome, ou remove a linha com o nome. Não tenho como saber em qual linha os nomes vão estar, por exemplo. Acho que vou ter q usar algum script mesmo =/

Comment: com o grep -n você consegue saber a linha que está o que você procura, dai você pode passar a linha como parâmetro

Answer (score 0):

Usando Awk tenta:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {c[$0]++} !c[$0]'  listanome.txt outro
```